# Soft question on the notion of connections

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question

We have met the notion of connection in different places:

1.For a vector bundle $E\to M$,a connection is defined to be a way of diffentiating a section of $E$ along a vector field of $M$,by which we have the parallel translation a given vector in $E$.

2.For a fibre bundle $F\to M$,a connection is defined to be a smooth distribution $u\mapsto H_u$ where $H_u$ intersects transversally with $V_u=T_u(F_p)$,by which we can also get the similar parallel translation.

My question is:

1.Can we find a unified way to define the notion of a connection both in a vector bundle and a fibre bundle?

2.What is the nature of a connection,basically,what things does it connects?Is the parallel translation we want in the very beginning so we go to define connections?

Any hints or book references would be much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, as a vector bundle is a special case of this bundle, and one can show that the two notions of a connection on a vector bundle coincide.

Comment: @Travis Thanks but,where can I find a proof?Any book references?

Comment: I learned this material out of a draft of a text that served as course notes (but alas are not yet published). There's a treatment of this (and IIRC a useful schematic diagram indicating the relationships among the various formulations of a connection) in Volume 2 of Spivak's *A comprehensive introduction to differential geometry*; Spivak's style is distinct and I mostly like it, but tastes vary. See also Section 6 of this list for more references: http://www.geometry.org/tex/conc/differential_geometry_books.html

Answer (score 2):

The second volume of Spivak's [*Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0914098713) is a wonderful place to learn about all the different forms of connections and how they relate to each other.